# Excel with conditional logic to find last row containing 'X'

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I don't even know if this is possible in Excel or not.  I'm needing a way to link subsequent rows with previous rows (children to a parent).

For example, Row 2 contains the parent information as denoted by an 'M' in column E.

If the parent has 3 children, rows 3,4,5, they're going to contain an 'S' or 'D' in column E.

If there's an 'S' or 'D' I need to fine the last row searching up that has an 'M' and then grab the value from the B column in that row (which is a unique ID for the parent) and insert it into a column in rows 3,4 & 5 to create a relationship between the 3 children and the one parent.  There will be cases where there are no children to any number of children, and so far we've been assured that the next row "up" will always be the parent for the subsequent children rows.

[image: Sample Data]

So in the above, because E3 and E4 are D (daughter) of Row 2, I need to take the B2 (UID) and put it in F3 and F4.  Since the next row is an M (parent) F5 is blank.  Row 6 is the child of row 5, so get B5 and copy it to F6.

Column B is a formula of first 3 letters of first name and dob formatted to YYYYMMDD and isn't necessary (but will be stored) for child rows.  Hope that clarifies!

Comment: Could you create an example - a few rows with the inputs and expected output / result?

Comment: I've updated the question with an image and explanation

Comment: Silly question - but you have a "son" with gender "F" and a "daughter" with gender "M"... is that deliberate? Should I not even be looking at column H?

Comment: Gender could also be for the parent.  Believe it or not this is insurance company data and they track "M" for member and then S and D for children.

Comment: That still doesn't explain why daughter Rachel would be F and daughter Skyler would be M... Incidentally if this is actual data I recommend that you remove it.

Comment: Not actual data.  Typo on my part all D should be F genders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that seems to work: the following formula would be written in `E4` (entered as an array formula, i.e. ctrl-shift-enter on PC or cmd-shift-enter on Mac), then copied down as needed. It requires there to be sufficient space above it (because you look "up to three above this row", that needs to be a valid row).

```
=IF(NOT(E4="M"),INDEX(B$1:B3,MAX((E1:E3="M")*ROW(E1:E3)))," ")
```

Explanation:

```
=IF(NOT(E4="M")    - check that this is not a "parent" (i.e. we need to do a lookup)
MAX((E1:E3="M")*ROW(E1:E3)))  - see what cell has an M. the (E1:E3) produces 0 or 1
                              - multiply by the row number and you get an array of 0 or row number
                              - the MAX of this is the last row number with an M
INDEX(B$1:B3, number)         - find the corresponding value in column B
                              - note the $ sign since the ROW is absolute row
" "                           - empty space when there IF is false (i.e. this is a parent)
```

Here is how it looked for me:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There may be a simpler way but...
`=IF(F12="",IF(E13<>"M",B12,""),IF(E13="M","",F12))`
looks to work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tend to solve this sort of situation with an extra column.  Column B has your ID, and Column E has the classification.  Let's say Column I (which can be hidden if the display is unhelpful) has the ID of the most recent parent.  Assume we are starting at Row 2 (you'll see why in a moment).  If E2 has "M", then we want the ID (B2); if it doesn't, we want to propagate the value from the previous row.  This is the formula which does that:

```
=IF(E2="M", B2, I1)
```

Then in Column F, your "Link To" column, use this formula:

```
=IF(E2="M", "", I2)
```

Fill down, and that's all you need.

**Updated to match newly posted image**

Comment: I added an image with some sample data that might clarify

Comment: For column I "has the ID of the most recent parent" how does that get filled in?

Comment: That is the first formula.  Just fill down in column I.

Answer (score 0):

Using your provided sample data, use this formula in cell F2 and copy down:

```
=IF(E2="M","",LOOKUP(2,1/(E$2:E2="M"),B$2:B2))
```